# Any way to specify the svn revision of externals in a Jenkins job?

Tags: svn, jenkins, svn-externals

Suppose I have such svn structure:

```
svn://myhost/repository_main
svn://myhost/repository_ext
```

*The revision numbers of these two repositories are **isolated**.*

Now I have set a `svn:externals` on `svn://myhost/repository_main/foo`:

```
svn://myhost/repository_main/foo --> svn://myhost/repository_ext/bar
```

Then in the Jenkins I have a job which uses the `svn://myhost/repository_main` and I could specify the revision number to update like:

```
svn://myhost/repository_main@REVISION
```

When the Jenkins is going to update the `/repository_main/foo` at revision `REVISION`, it always update to the `HEAD` revision of the `repository_ext/bar`.

Is there any way I could specify not only the revision of the `main` but also the `ext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `externals` mechanism uses it's own specified revision. This is nothing to do with Jenkins. Even without Jenkins (through browser or your SVN client), if you try to checkout from your `repository_main` with specified revision, it will take the `HEAD` for `repository_ext`

`externals` is an SVN property. It specifies 2 things:

1. The remote (external) location
2. The revision of that location

If you configured that property to remote `HEAD`, it will always be `HEAD` of remote location, even when you go to previous revision of your `main`. Think of it as a local file with a value. If the file had a value `remote@HEAD` at `main` revision `100` and hasn't changed since then, when you are at `main` revision `200`, the value of the file is still `remote@HEAD`. And when you go to `main` at revision `199`, that file still points to `remote@HEAD`

Your other option is to lock the `external` to a specific revision, i.e `remote@123`, but then it will **always** be at that `ext` revision, again regardless of the `main` revision.

If you have a hard dependency between the revision of code in `main` and the appropriate `ext` revision, then your `externals` property should not be pointing at `HEAD` of remote, but at specified revision. You would need some process to keep the property updated with latest required revision. 
If you do that, your `external` property may be `remote@123` at `main` revision `100`, and then `remote@456` at `main` revision `150` and then `remote@789` at `main` revision `200`.

Only in that case, specifying a `main` revision would affect the revision of the external repository that is fetched up.

**Alternative:**
As a complete workaround (what is described above is how SVN expects you to work with it), you can have a Jenkins parameter for "externals revision". Then in SCM steps, tell Jenkins to ignore externals. Then in your Build steps, manually parse the value of the externals property, figure out the remote location, and manually check out from that location with the revision that you specified in parameters.